# select2 search textbox looses focus after selecting value from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin for the first time in my ASP.NET project. I am getting a problem that after selecting item from the drop down the textbox looses focus. 
I tired with this code but it is not working. Please help me.

```
$(function () {
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
            $('.select2').select2(
            {
                    onSelect: function ()
                    {
                        this.focus();
                    }
                }
            )
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean with it loose focus. when i run your code it works just fine, also without the onselect function http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1597/

Comment: I mean when I select item from the dropdown the select2 textbox looses focus. I've to use mouse again to browse my form control. Please try once.

Comment: This was an issue in 4.0.3.  Have you upgraded to the latest version (4.0.6-rc.0 at the time of this post)?

Comment: Just now I downloaded and kept the select2 from https://github.com/select2/select2 . Still the issue, shall I've to add some javascript? Please reply. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4384#issuecomment-228464364 It worked for me.

```
$('select').on(
    'select2:close',
    function () {
        $(this).focus();
    }
);
```

Thank You!